# SQL to get top 3 most ordered products for every user by quantity sold

Tags: mysql, sql, e-commerce

I am working on a school project the idea of which is an eCommerce site for selling beers.

I need to get the top 3 most ordered products for every individual user that has ordered something. My database includes 4 tables: users, products, orders and order_detail. The diagram is:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/PofTxjQ]

I think I will have to join all 4 of the tables to get that info, but I can't figure out the correct way to do it. Here is what I have generated:

```
SELECT u.username, p.`id` AS productId, p.`name`, od.`quantity` AS quantity
FROM `order_detail` AS od
    INNER JOIN `products` AS p
    INNER JOIN `users` AS u
    ON od.`product_id` = p.`id`
GROUP BY od.`order_id`, p.name
ORDER BY od.`quantity` DESC, p.`name` ASC
```

The database script: https://pastebin.com/BvQLGqur

Comment: Try this:

SELECT u.username,  p.`name`, sum(od.`quantity`) AS quantity
FROM `order_detail` AS od
    INNER JOIN `products` AS p
    INNER JOIN `users` AS u
    ON od.`product_id` = p.`id`
GROUP BY u.username, p.name
ORDER BY od.`quantity` DESC, p.`name` ASC

Comment: Instead of paste bin, you may want to use SQL Fiddle since few will want to expend the amount of effort to read through all that code.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In order to limit the rows returned to show just the top 3 products ordered for each user, you'll need to use a sub-query with a limit clause on the order_detail.

Other than that, it just a simple join between the 4 tables.

```
SELECT
    a.`user_name`,
    d.`id` as `product_id`,
    d.`name` as `product_name`,
    SUM(c1.`quantity`) as `total_quantity`,
    d.`price` as `product_price`,
    d.`price` * SUM(c1.`quantity`) as `total_spent`
FROM `users` a
JOIN `orders` b
    ON b.`user_id` = a.`id`
JOIN (SELECT c.`order_id`, c.`product_id`, SUM(c.`quantity`) as `num_ordered`
        FROM `order_detail` c
        ORDER BY `num_ordered` DESC
        LIMIT 3) as c1
    ON c1.`order_id` = b.`id`
JOIN `products` d
    ON d.`id` = c1.`product_id`
GROUP BY a.`id`,d.`product_id`
ORDER BY a.`user_name`,`total_quantity` DESC, d.`name`;
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the question raised after running the query on the db structure although there are still some errors on the query

Comment: How so? It will produce a list of all users who have ordered products, and list the top 3 products by order quantity in descending order.

Comment: I think he needs the top 3 products for each user and cumulative top 3 products

Comment: Yes i need the top 3 products for each user individually

Comment: A few issues with your query looking at the schema provided; 1. `a.user_name` is supposed to be `a.username` 2. There is no field called `quantity` on alias `c1`

Comment: try this  `SELECT b.user_id, a.username, b.product_name, b.product_id, b.product_description, b.order_qty 
FROM users a
 JOIN  (SELECT username, u.id AS 'user_id', p.name AS 'product_name', 
   p.description AS 'product_description', 
   p.id AS 'product_id', u.last_name, u.first_name,
   SUM(od.quantity) AS 'order_qty' FROM products p
LEFT JOIN order_detail od ON p.id=od.product_id
LEFT JOIN orders o ON od.order_id=o.id
LEFT JOIN users u ON o.user_id=u.id
WHERE product_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY u.username, p.id
ORDER BY u.username, order_qty DESC) AS b ON a.id=b.user_id;`

Comment: that does it, correct. I just need to limit results to 3, thanks!